# cordova build windows in windows 7 failed

Tags: cordova

When I run the command "cordova build windows" I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target.
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I don't have Visual Studio installed on my machine. I have .Net 4 installed, the Cordova version used is 5.3.3. and my 
OS is Windows 7.

Please suggest a way to build without using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to have a running windows 8 or 8.1 machine to proceed. Please read the [Cordova platform guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/win8/index.html) for further information.

Comment: Thank you Beat. Is there any other way of doing this in windows 7 using visual studio or so.

Comment: I don't think so, because these are the requirements by cordova. You need the specific environment, in your case windows 8, if you want to build for that.